# Fastet way to position a double in an existing vector

Tags: r, list

Let's say I have a double like 3.5 and I would like to find out where to sort it in an existing sorted vector say `seq(1, 10)`, put differently, which index the new number would take in the vector. Of course it sits somewhere between 3 and 4 and hence between the third and fourth index, but what would be the fastet way to arrive at this result?

Comment: Is your existing vector sorted or unsorted?

Comment: `findInterval(3.5, 1:10)` returns `3`, meaning it belongs after the third element in the `1:10` vector.

Comment: @Onyambu I forgot to mention it, but yes it is sorted. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: use `findInterval` that should be optimized for this task

Comment: @r2evans post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `findInterval` is fastest for this purpose. Even a very simple loop in C++ that does the same thing is a little slower on average.

```r
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction("int find_index(double x, NumericVector v) {
            int len = v.size();
            for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
             if(x <= v[i]) return i + 1;
            }
            return NA_INTEGER;
}")

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  findInterval = findInterval(453993.5, 1:1000000),
  find_index   = find_index(453993.5, 1:1000000)
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>          expr    min     lq      mean  median     uq      max neval
#>  findInterval 1.9646 2.1739  2.996931 2.32375 2.4846  37.4218   100
#>    find_index 2.2151 2.4502 11.319199 2.60925 2.9800 337.9229   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

First define `dbl` and `my_seq`
then concatenate both with `c(dbl, my_seq)` and wrap it with `sort`

then define the index with `which(my_vec == dbl)`:

```
dbl <- 3.5
my_seq <- seq(1,10)
my_vec <- sort(c(dbl, my_seq))
index <- which(my_vec == dbl)
index
```

output:

```
[1] 4
```